# RecyclerView for large items

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

In our app we have a `RecyclerView` that shows large items in horizontal list. We use LinearLayoutManager to do that. The issue occurs when user scrolls the screen. When next large items needs to appear on a screen UI is frozen.

What we wanted to implement is some kind of lazy loading for `RecyclerView` item. So that similar to facebook's implementation user saw an stub, and once he stopped scrolling UI would update to show actual content.

The question is - what is the correct extension point for that? Should I implement custom `LayoutManager`? Or there are existing solutions for that?

Comment: can you put up code to show what you're currently doing?

Comment: I'm not sure what code to put here. Here is a code for recycler view that we use https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin as your tag say you can do this:

```
public class  XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
    public delegate void LoadMoreEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event LoadMoreEventHandler LoadMoreEvent;

    private LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager;

    public XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener (LinearLayoutManager layoutManager)
    {
        LayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public override void OnScrolled (RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        base.OnScrolled (recyclerView, dx, dy);

        var visibleItemCount = recyclerView.ChildCount;
        var totalItemCount = recyclerView.GetAdapter().ItemCount;
        var pastVisiblesItems = LayoutManager.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
            LoadMoreEvent (this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this in your view use:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
        if (recyclerView != null)
        {
            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);

            var onScrollListener = new XamarinRecyclerViewOnScrollListener (layoutManager);
            onScrollListener.LoadMoreEvent += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                //Load more stuff here
            };

            recyclerView.AddOnScrollListener (onScrollListener);

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what you're doing, I can only make a high level suggestion.  And that suggestion is attaching a scroll listener to the recyclerView.

How would this work for you?

```
        final int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    final int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    myRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            switch (newState) {
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    for (int i = firstVisiblePosition; i <= lastVisiblePosition; i++) {
                        // start content loading here
                        recyclerView.getChildAt(i).loadMyContent;
                    }
                    break;
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                    for (int i = firstVisiblePosition; i <= lastVisiblePosition; i++) {
                        // cancel content loading here
                        recyclerView.getChildAt(i).cancelLoad;
                    }
                    break;
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                    // you could load content here, but it could end up off screen by the time it stops, so I would not recommend it
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to add that if you are loading images, take a look at the [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

From Picasso's webpage:

**ADAPTER DOWNLOADS**

*Adapter re-use is automatically detected and the previous download canceled.*

```
@Override public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    view = new SquaredImageView(context);
  }
  String url = getItem(position);

  Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);
}
```